# Different locations mktime issue

Tags: python, datetime, time

I'm facing a problem with dates in python. I'm getting different results with mktime, in different places.

On my local server, if I try:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> from time import mktime
>>> mydate = date(2008,1,1)
>>> mktime(mydate.timetuple())
1199156400.0
>>> mydate2 = date(1998,1,1)
>>> mktime(mydate2.timetuple())
883620000.0
```

But if I try it on another server, I get:

```
>>> mydate = date(2008,1,1)
>>> mktime(mydate.timetuple())
1199152800.0
>>> mydate2 = date(1998,1,1)
>>> mktime(mydate2.timetuple())
883620000.0
```

Note that, in the fisrt case, the result was different. But in the second, it was the same.

Both python versions are the same.
I've also checked some time variables, like accept2dyear, altzone, daylight, tzname and timezone They are the same in both servers too.

Should I check some other thing?

Comment: Can you show the output of `mydate.timetuple()[8]` for both servers and both dates?

Comment: In both situations they were the same. It was only diverging when mktime was being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In My local server, my timezone is set as America/Bahia, and in the other server it's America/Sao_Paulo.

In some years, the daylight wasn't applied to Bahia, so it seems that it was causing this one-hour difference between times.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where exactly the server is, the timezone of that location may have changed between 1998 and 2008.  For example, some counties switched time zones in 2006 and 2007.  One server may have correct timezone data for a particular location and the other may not.